# Change interior color of range of cells without using loops

Tags: excel, vba

How to make this work?

```
Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(height,width)).Interior.Color=colorArray
```

colorArray is one-dimensional array of Long Integers of length (width*height) containing color values.

The above code returns

> Type mismatch error.

```
For i = 1 to height
   For j = 1 to width
      t=(i-1)*width+j
      Cells(i,j).Interior.Color=colorArray(t)
   Next
Next
```

This code works but is too slow. I dont want to use loops.

```
Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(height,width)).Value=colorArray
```

This code fills the range with color values from the colorArray with no error. I want a similar code to change background color of cells of this range.

Please help.

```
ReDim colorArray(1 To width*height) As Long
```

Sample code by Siddharth Rout:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim colorArray(21) 'or Dim colorArray(21) As Long/Integer
    Dim Height As Long, Width As Long

    For i = 0 To 21
        colorArray(i) = i
    Next

    Height = 10
    Width = 2

    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Height, Width)).Interior.Color = colorArray

End Sub
```

This code also returns

> "Run-time error: '13' Type mismatch"

Comment: Hmmm that is surprising. I retested my code and it is working just fine. Can you upload your workbook say at www.wikisend.com and paste the link here so that I can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the problem lies in your call.  You should use:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Height, Width)).Interior.Color***Index*** = colorArray
```

That is my experience using cell background colors in Excel VBA.

-Scott