# How to set background color in a range using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I am trying. But it shows type mismatch error.
I don't want to use for loop for setting colors to individual cell.

```
Function bgColor()
    Dim MyArray(1, 3) As Variant
    MyArray(0, 0) = 37
    MyArray(0, 1) = 12
    MyArray(0, 2) = 15
    MyArray(0, 3) = 18
    Sheets("Data").Range("A1:D1").Interior.ColorIndex = MyArray
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: You are already assigning the array one by one. skip that and just set each cell one by one.

Comment: @ScottCraner There are 100s of cells and it takes time. So if I could assign a full array it would save some seconds.

Comment: If you are assigning the items in the array one at a time like your example then it is actually shorter to just assign the color directly to each cell.

Comment: If that is not how you are filling the array then change the example to show how you are filling the array.

Comment: The thing is I/O operations takes time and assigning values to a variable is different than storing values in spreadsheet cells.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't change cell formatting with `Function`, try as a `Sub` instead?

Comment: I can see that, but as far as I know you will not get around the individual assignment, either line by line or a loop with the array.

Comment: @ScottCraner Setting values with array works. Even two dimensional. Then why not cell background ? Is there any reference ?

Comment: @BruceWayne Same error with sub as well

Comment: You can only set values using an array - you cannot assign colors that way.

Comment: Ok, but can you point me to some URL which says that ? I want to see the documentation.

Comment: @HariDas Documentation doesn't typically say what you *can't* do. The absence of any mention of setting colors via an array can't be directly inked to.

Comment: Here in this link a dev says it works.. Not sure how it worked. I am getting error. Here is the link for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325072/excel-vba-change-interior-color-of-range-of-cells-without-using-loops?rq=1

Comment: @HariDas That is odd. The code definitely doesn't work in Excel 2016. Perhaps at one time it did work (in an undocumented way?) in some earlier versions (no telling what version that code was using) but no longer works. Even in that answer back in 2014, some people were reporting that the code was throwing a type mismatch error. On the other hand, there is no doubt that if Siddharth Rout (a true guru) had written it, then it worked at the time.

Comment: Speculating a bit: At one time Excel just had a restricted color palate. Now you can use 24-bit colors in the cells. Some nontrivial changes under the hood must have occurred (quite likely more than one change over 2 or 3 Excel versions). It seems that one of these changes broke the behavior in Siddharth Rout's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Looping through an array of 5000 colors and writing them to cells took far less than a second, even with screenupdating on. Is there another reason you can't use a `For` loop?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyArray(0, 4999) As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 4999
        MyArray(0, i) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 40)
    Next i

    For i = 0 To 4999
        Sheets("Data").Cells(i + 1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = MyArray(0, i)
    Next i

End Sub
```